# react native state value changing randomly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native

The data blob of the first console.log(this.state.dataSource) gives me

```
  [ { date: '2017-07-13',
      images: 
       [ { image: 'assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=8855847A-7157-4D04-8E71-43746BED3E2E&ext=JPG',
           selected: false } ],
      key: 0 }]
```

The second console.log(this.state.dataSource) gives me data blob:

```
  [ { date: '2017-07-13',
      images: 
       [ { image: 'assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=8855847A-7157-4D04-8E71-43746BED3E2E&ext=JPG',
           selected: true } ],
      key: 0 }]
```

As you can see, I never did setState in this function to change value of this.state.dataSource, how is it that somehow, my function is also affecting the value of this.state.dataSource? It seems there is direct manipulation of that state value due to this line

```
tempImages[index].selected = !tempImages[index].selected
```

_

```
setSelected(date,index,value){
    console.log(this.state.dataSource)
    let tempArray = data
    let tempImages = []
    for(var i in tempArray){
        if(tempArray[i].date == date){
            tempImages = tempArray[i].images
        }
    }
    console.log(tempImages)
    tempImages[index].selected = !tempImages[index].selected
    console.log(tempImages)
    console.log(this.state.dataSource)
}
```

edit:

```
sortPhotos(value){
    let tempArray = []
    for(var i in value){
        let found = false
        for(var e in tempArray){
            if(tempArray[e].date == moment(value[i].node.timestamp*1000).format('YYYY-MM-DD')){
                found = e
            }
        }
        if(!found){
            tempArray.push({
                date: moment(value[i].node.timestamp*1000).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                images: [{image: value[i].node.image.uri, selected: false}],
                key: tempArray.length
            })
        }else{
            let images = tempArray[found].images
            images.push({
                image: value[i].node.image.uri,
                selected: false
            })
            tempArray[found].images = images
        }
    }
    this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(tempArray),
        dataSourceClean: tempArray,
        loaded: true
    })
}

setSelected(date,index,value){
    let tempArray = this.state.dataSourceClean
    let tempImages = []
    for(var i in tempArray){
        if(tempArray[i].date == date){
            tempImages = tempArray[i].images
        }
    }
    tempImages[index].selected = !tempImages[index].selected
    console.log(this.state.dataSource)
}
```

Comment: `tempImages[index].selected = !tempImages[index].selected`. yes it is. It's modifying the inner state object, as object is stored by reference in js

Comment: Yes I realised I have mutation. I edited the question with more code, could you help me fix it up to remove the mutation? I'm not sure how to handle object/references

Comment: This is why immutability is so popular among React devs - better to never assign any property directly, so you don't end up mutating from object reference. `Object.assign` to a new object, and object spread operators (e.g. `let foo = { ...bar, newprop: true };`), are a great (but shallow) way to do this. btw it's not a blob, and `dataSource` is a bad name for a state prop. Of course it's data.

Comment: Could you post an answer please?

Answer (score 0):

You are cloning your `dataSource` with an array, that cloning will be done using reference to `tempArray`, so whenever you made changes to `tempArray` those change will be reflected in `dataSource`. You have to do something like this in your code :

`dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows([...tempArray])`

What we are doing with `[...tempArray]` is that we are passing a copy of `tempArray` which is in no way associated with `tempArray`, any changes you make in `tempArray` will not reflect in `dataSource`.

**PS**

- In Javascript strings, numbers are assigned using values (new copies) whereas Arrays, Objects, Dates are assigned as references (points to same object).
- The `...` is Spread operator introduced in ES6. You can learn more about it here [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)